# Dropdowns that filters my database and update the next dropboxes

Tags: php, javascript, filter

I have a form and I want to filter in real time my database(Postgresql) when I choose a value from a dropbox, without a submit button, like this site:

[toshiba filter form example](http://pt.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/download_drivers_bios.jsp?service=PT)

I prefer options in javascript or php,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery SelectChain plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/selectchain) is a very easy way to get started.